# Почему python3.11 не хочет запускать FoxDot?

Tags: python-3.x

https://foxdotcode.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guides/installation.html

Устанавливаю по этому гайду и до этого момента все окей:

[Startup](https://foxdotcode.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guides/installation.html#startup)

а когда запускаю:

```
python3 -m FoxDot
```

не работает и выводит вот такую ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 189, in _run_module_as_main
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 148, in _get_module_details
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 112, in _get_module_details
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/FoxDot-0.8.12-py3.11.egg/FoxDot/__init__.py", line 106, in <module>
    from .lib import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/FoxDot-0.8.12-py3.11.egg/FoxDot/lib/__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from .TempoClock import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/FoxDot-0.8.12-py3.11.egg/FoxDot/lib/TempoClock.py", line 53, in <module>
    from .Players import Player
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/FoxDot-0.8.12-py3.11.egg/FoxDot/lib/Players.py", line 141, in <module>
    from .Key import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/FoxDot-0.8.12-py3.11.egg/FoxDot/lib/Key.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .Patterns import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/FoxDot-0.8.12-py3.11.egg/FoxDot/lib/Patterns/__init__.py", line 72, in <module>
    from .Main       import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/FoxDot-0.8.12-py3.11.egg/FoxDot/lib/Patterns/Main.py", line 81, in <module>
    class metaPattern(object):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/FoxDot-0.8.12-py3.11.egg/FoxDot/lib/Patterns/Main.py", line 632, in metaPattern
    @loop_pattern_method
     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/FoxDot-0.8.12-py3.11.egg/FoxDot/lib/Patterns/Main.py", line 61, in loop_pattern_method
    new_function.argspec = inspect.getargspec(f)
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: module 'inspect' has no attribute 'getargspec'. Did you mean: 'getargs'?
```

ОС: Kali Linux

Comment: Гуглится же легко ошибка. Там что-то поменяли в модуле `inspect`. Либо откатываться на предыдущие какие-то совместимые с этой либой версии питона, либо руками менять в коде либы там где ошибка вызов `getargspec` на `getfullargspec`.